# css: Image loading returning 404

Tags: css, iis

I'm trying to load an image as a background off the server on my CDN subdomain. I'm using:
`url ("http://cdn.domain.toplevel/website/image/imagename.jpg")` to load it. It works fine but when I look in browsers, a `/` is appended to the end, causing my web server to return 404. Is there any way I can stop this?

Comment: Please share relevant HTML, CSS, and console errors.

Comment: share use case and an working url